# WPF designer error due to incorrect running assembly path

Tags: wpf, error-handling, path, designer

I have a control that upon loading parses an XML file with country names and later populates a ComboBox. I access my XML as following:

```
 public DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds.ReadXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\..\Resources\XML\countries.xml");
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

GetData is called inside control's Loaded handler.

At design time, however, I get an error saying that directory does not exist with the XML file and as you see it is looking in the wrong AppDomain path (Visual Studio, not project):

[image]

How can I resolve this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to avoid this is to wrap the code in a check to see if it is running in the designer.

```
DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)
```

Will return true in design mode, and false when the app is running "for real" (if called from a DesignerObject).  You should only try to read your xml when not in design mdoe.

Comment: That works, have just finished reading about this at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546934%28VS.90%29.aspx